# What is the URL query parameter for 'Tiles' view in a Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, url, quick-links

I can create a `Link` in a `Quick Links` `Web Part` with a URL of:

```
https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/MyDocLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=My_x0020_Column&FilterValue1=My%20Value
```

Can I add a URL query parameter so that users see the library in `Tiles` view when clicking on the link?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any query parameter for Tiles view.

But, you can save the default document library view as a **Tiles** view from **Switch view options** dropdown.

[image]

Comment: FYI - I could add the following link in `Quick Links` web part, but you have to click `Insert` quickly, otherwise the URL is stripped of the `View` and `Filter` parameters.  Steps to create:   `Create new view` of type `Gallery` which creates URL like: `https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/Media/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewid=some-long-id-here&id=%2Fsites%2Fmy-site%2Fmy-document-library` and then append filter, eg: `&useFiltersInViewXml=1&FilterField1=My-Column-Name&FilterValue1=Some%20Value`.  Use that link as the URL in a `Quick Link`.

Comment: This is similar what I was suggesting. Either you create a new gallery view or set existing default view to gallery layout & pass view URL in quick links.